# How I can draw GridColor in canvas blazor

Tags: canvas, grid, blazor, webassembly

I want to draw a color grid chart on Blazor web assembly,but dont found any information how i can do it, except drawing small multicolor rectangles.
But I want set a data array in color grid object, like i can do it in TeeChart library for RadStudio.

Can someone get advice/link for me?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use inline svg.  This allows me to fairly easily add / change data points and so on, and because it's inline, everything can be parameterized in Blazor.  Also, because svg is vector, all text or lines can be scaled up or down without losing quality.

Comment: Please, can you give me example how i can draw color grid with gradient scale on svg using data points.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of what you're looking for?

Comment: http://www.steema.net/TeeChartForNET/index.aspx
Select chapter Chart Styles, and then Statistical, and then Color Grid

Comment: The visual presentation for that kind of chart would be trivial: as you say, just a bunch of colored squares.  For very high resolution settings, maybe a generated image would be better than .svg or html canvas.  But I'm 'not really familiar with this kind of "chart".  To my eyes, it's a heat map which is being quantized at different scales-- but what is the format of the original data?  Also, IMO you should uncheck my post as "answered" because it doesn't really answer your question well.

Comment: format is also contains physical values like temperature and pressure.
I make analog from colored squares . but his so slow(6-7 fps, i need 15). because i make many object with different parameters, and then draw his like rectangle.
I think is not optimized

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm good with Blazor, but I cannot represent data I don't clearly understand.  gl with your search!